# How to convert hex color string to RGB using regex in C++

Tags: c++, regex, hex

How to convert the hex color string to RGB using regex?

I am using the regex but it is not working. I am not familiar with regex. Is it the correct way?

Below is the sample code:

```
int main()
{
    std::string l_strHexValue = "#FF0000";

    std::regex pattern("#?([0-9a-fA-F]{2}){3}");

    std::smatch match;
    if (std::regex_match(l_strHexValue, match, pattern))
    {
        auto r = (uint8_t)std::stoi(match[1].str(), nullptr, 16);
        auto g = (uint8_t)std::stoi(match[2].str(), nullptr, 16);
        auto b = (uint8_t)std::stoi(match[3].str(), nullptr, 16);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The regex must be `std::regex pattern("#([0-9a-fA-F]{2})([0-9a-fA-F]{2})([0-9a-fA-F]{2})\\b");`

Comment: Please don't use C-style casting. Use `static_cast<uint8_t>(...)` instead.

Comment: Also, you don't really need regular expressions here (most of the time it's overkill), if you know the input string is in the correct format to begin with. Then use either `substr()` to get two digits at a time to convert. Or use arithmetic to convert digit by digit.

Comment: Why don't you use an online bytes to long conversion tool. Or an hex to long, then split to bytes Win32 is good macro RGB( )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```cpp
std::regex pattern("#([0-9a-fA-F]{2})([0-9a-fA-F]{2})([0-9a-fA-F]{2})");
```

Here, the `FF`, `00` and `00` are captured into a separate group.

Or, you can use a bit different approach.

```cpp
std::string l_strHexValue = "#FF0000";
std::regex pattern("#([0-9a-fA-F]{6})");
std::smatch match;
if (std::regex_match(l_strHexValue, match, pattern))
{
    int r, g, b;
    sscanf(match.str(1).c_str(), "%2x%2x%2x", &r, &g, &b);
    std::cout << "R: " << r << ", G: " << g << ", B: " << b << "\n";
}
// => R: 255, G: 0, B: 0
```

See the [C++ demo](https://ideone.com/CAFc1l).